# Generating a new class dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic

I want to write some code that creates a new class dynamically and store it in a `.cs` file.  
I was wondering if there is a standard way of doing this other than just creating strings and writing these to a text file? Basically, I have written an object oriented Neural Net and I want it to be able to output a highly optimized hard wired final version of itself to a new class for use in other code.

Comment: What is the business purpose behind generating new classes dynamically?

Comment: It's something I'm working on in my spare time.  I have an interest in Artificial Intelligence

Comment: I do too, could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to generate a class which simply performs the calculations for a trained feed forward network.  Just a black box with inputs and outputs for use in other code.  I want to see how fast I can get it to run.

Comment: So you'll need a ton of these to do it genetically? What would it be about using a file that would actually make your process faster?

Comment: No the idea is that I will train a network using my existing code and then write a stripped down version of the trained network to a new class.  I don't know if it will run faster or not at this stage but I'm betting there will be a small improvement.

Comment: Won't the class be just a set of doubles or whatever you're using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19036/discussion-between-paul-matthews-and-yuriy-faktorovich)

Answer (score 1):

Use [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to generate the file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to writing out the strings into a text file, which is the simplest option that should work for small projects, you could use *template engines*. Several options are available in .NET:

- **[Text Template Transformation Toolkit (T4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx)** - A template engine from Microsoft. T4 is used throughout Visual Studio for code generation.
- **[String Template Engine](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)** - A template engine from the designers of ANTLR, a popular parser generator.